# Specify response_type=token for SSO in Identity Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, identityserver4

I am attempting to set up SSO from our ASP.NET Core Identity Server app to an external identity provider. Basically a user that is authenticated on our external partner's website but isn't authenticated on our website clicks a link to go to a certain page on our website. Since they aren't authenticated on our website then it redirects them to the external identity provider's authentication request url, then after verifying they are authenticated it redirects them back to our identity server to sign them in then redirects them to the original page that they requested.

This works great with the authorization code flow (response_type=code), it seems that this is the default in Identity Server. However, one of the external identity providers that we're trying to integrate with does not support the authorization code flow, when I try it they return an error: "The+authorization+server+does+not+support+obtaining+an+authorization+code+using+this+method". They only support response_type=token. It's not clear to me how you can specify this in Identity Server, it appends response_type=code into the authentication request url no matter what. Even if I specify ?response_type=token in my authentication request url it STILL appends response_type=code after that. And I don't see any property on the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth.OAuthOptions class that can be used to configure it. What am I missing?

```
authenticationBuilder.AddOAuth(ssoIdentityProvider.SsoCode, options => SetOAuth2Options(ssoIdentityProvider, options));

private static void SetOAuth2Options(IdentityProvider ssoIdentityProvider, OAuthOptions options)
        {
            // Set standard options.
            options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
            options.AuthorizationEndpoint = ssoIdentityProvider.AuthenticationRequestUrl;
            options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-oauth2");
            options.ClientId = ssoIdentityProvider.OAuth2ClientId;
            options.ClientSecret = ssoIdentityProvider.OAuth2ClientSecret;
            options.UsePkce = ssoIdentityProvider.OAuth2UsePkce;
            options.TokenEndpoint = ssoIdentityProvider.OAuth2TokenRequestUrl;
            options.UserInformationEndpoint = ssoIdentityProvider.OAuth2UserInformationRequestUrl;
            // Set requested scopes.
            ssoIdentityProvider.OAuth2RequestedScopesList?.ForEach(s => options.Scope.Add(s));
            // Set expected claims.
            ssoIdentityProvider.OAuth2ExpectedClaimsList.ForEach(c => options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(c.Key, c.Value));
            options.Validate();
        }
```

Comment: The OpenID Connect and OAuth 2 specs define the following grant types:
Implicit, Authorization code. Hybrid, Client credentials, Resource owner password, Device flow, Refresh tokens, Extension grants. You can specify which grant type a client can use via the `AllowedGrantTypes` property on the Client configuration. So, please check the `Config.cs` file, and set the `AllowedGrantTypes` property. Besides, based on your description, you might want to set the response_code to code or token, you could try to use the Hybrid Flow, refer [this table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1B2aQ.png).

Comment: Reference: [Grant Types](https://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/grant_types.html) and [IdentityServer 4 Samples](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/main/samples).

Comment: @ZhiLv I changed my identity server website to add the "hybrid" grant type to its supported list and removed the other grant type that we were previously adding ("client_credentials"), and yet it still sends response_type=code when I call the Challenge method.